# WHOIS privacy help

Tags: domain-name-system, security, whois, privacy

How do I protect my identy from whois?  If someone whois's my domain name, it reveals my name, address etc etc.  How do I hide this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to contact whoever you registered your domain with and see if they have an option to remove your details from the public register.

I can't remember the exact name for this and your registration company might call it something different anyway.

It may be a chargeable extra.

Comment: How about http://privacyprotect.org ?

Comment: @oshirowanen - I didn't know about them. It looks like a mechanism to contact domain owners who are hidden. Hopefully it won't reveal your details to the user until after you've responded.

Answer (score 2):

another option is to get a PO Box - may be called something different in your area

an direct the Whois information to that PO Box that way you will not be giving out your address for the world to see :)

Answer (score 1):

"anonymous domain registration" and "domain privacy" are offered by some domain registrars.
If your registrar doesn't offer this service, you can switch to one who will.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_privacy